# How to send Wei to payable function with ethers

Tags: ethereum, solidity, hardhat

I want to send this function **1 wei** using ethersJS while testing it on hardhat:

```
modifier payFee() {
   bool sent = payable(address(this)).send(msg.value);
   require(sent, "Didn't receive fee.");
    _;
}

function executeTrade(
    address _tokenA,
    address _tokenB,
    uint _tokensFromFlashLoan,
    bool _startOnUniswap
) external payable payFee {
    uint balanceBefore = IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(_tokenA);
    bytes memory data = abi.encode(
        _startOnUniswap,
        _tokenA,
        _tokenB,
        _tokensFromFlashLoan,
        balanceBefore
    );
    flashloan(_tokenA, _tokensFromFlashLoan, data);
}
```

I'm currently doing it like this:

```
const options = {
        gasLimit: 3000000,
        value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("1.0", "wei"),
      };

      trade = await contract.executeTrade(
        tokenA,
        tokenB,
        ethers.utils.parseEther("10.0"),
        false,
        options
      );
```

And i tried doing this but it doesn't work:

```
const options = {
    gasLimit: 3000000,
    value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("1.0", "wei"),
};

trade = await contract.executeTrade(
    tokenA,
    tokenB,
    ethers.utils.parseEther("10.0"),
    false,
    { ...options }
);
```

The modifier reverts giving me an error saying that the function didn't receive the fee, is my method to send **1** **WEI** wrong? if you have any suggestion please reply it would be very helpful.

Comment: What version of Ethers are you using?

Comment: im using the ^5.4.7

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside the smart contract.

```
bool sent = payable(address(this)).send(msg.value);
```

The statement above tries to send to itself, and if your contract does not implement `fallback()`, it can't receive, so send returns false, which makes the contract revert due to following statement: `require(sent, "Didn't receive fee.");` hence the error message.

This also looks like a bug; why would you want to send value from a contract to itself?